# How to design filters for a generic, pluggable collection?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections, filter

I am developing a web application that features a timeline, much like a Facebook timeline. The timeline itself is completely generic and pluggable. It's just a generic collection of items. Anything with the proper interface (`Dateable`) can be added to the collection and displayed on the timeline.

Other components (Symfony bundles) define models that implement the `Dateable` interface and set up a provider that can find and return these models. The code is much like this:

```
class Timeline
{
    private $providers = []; // Filled by DI

    public function find(/* ... */)
    {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($this->providers as $provider) {
            $result = array_merge($result, $provider->find(/* ... */));
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

The problem is that there needs to be a set of filters next to the timeline. Some filter options (like `date`) apply to all providers. But most options do not. For example, most providers will be able to use the `author` filter option, but not all. Some notification item are dynamically generated and don't have an author.

Some filter options just apply to a single provider. For example, only event items have a `location` property.

I can't figure out how to design a filter form that is just as modular as the timeline itself. Where should the available filter options be defined? Bundle-specific filter options could probably come from the bundle itself, but how about filter options (like `user`) that can be used by multiple bundles? And what if some filter options later become usable by multiple bundles? For example, only events have a `location` now, but what if another module is added that also has items with a location?

And how will each provider determine if the submitted filter form only contains options it understands? If I set a location in the filter then the `BlogPostProvider` should not return any messages, because blog posts have no location. But I can't check for `location` in the filter because the BlogPostBundle shouldn't know about other providers and their filtering options.

Any ideas on how I can design such a filter form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it in the end.

First off, I have a `FilterRegistry`. Any bundle can add filters to it using a Symfony DI tag. A filter is simply a form type. Example filter:

```
class LocationFilterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('location', 'choice', [ /* ... */ ]);
    }
}
```

DI configuration:

```
<service id="filter.location" class="My\Bundle\Form\LocationFilterType">
    <tag name="form.type" alias="filter_location" />
    <tag name="filter.type" alias="location" />
</service>
```

The `FilterRegistry` knows how to get those form types from the DI container:

```
class FilterRegistry
{
    public function getFormType($name)
    {
        if (!isset($this->types[$name])) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Unknown filter type "%s"', $name));
        }

        return $this->container->get($this->types[$name]);
    }
}
```

The `Timeline` class and the providers use the `FilterBuilder` to add new filters to the filter form. The builder looks like this:

```
class FilterBuilder
{
    public function __construct(FilterRegistry $filterRegistry, FormBuilderInterface $formBuilder)
    {
        $this->filterRegistry = $filterRegistry;
        $this->formBuilder = $formBuilder;
    }

    public function add($name)
    {
        if ($this->formBuilder->has($name)) {
            return;
        }

        $type = $this->filterRegistry->getFormType($name);
        $type->buildForm($this->formBuilder, $this->formBuilder->getOptions());

        return $this;
    }
}
```

In order to display the form, a filter is build using the options of all providers. This happens in `Timeline->getFilterForm()`. Note that there is no data object tied to the form:

```
class Timeline
{
    public function getFilterForm()
    {
        $formBuilder = $this->formFactory->createNamedBuilder('', 'base_filter_type');

        foreach ($this->providers as $provider) {
            $provider->configureFilter(new FilterBuilder($this->filterRegistry, $formBuilder));
        }

        return $formBuilder->getForm();
    }
}
```

Each provider implements the `configureFilter` method:

```
class EventProvider
{
    public function configureFilter(FilterBuilder $builder)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('location')
            ->add('author')
        ;
    }
}
```

The `find` method of the Timeline class is also modified. Instead of building a filter with all options, it builds a new filter form with just the options for that provider. If form validation fails then the provider cannot handle the currently submitted combination of filters. Usually this is because a filter option is set that the provider does not understand. In that case, form validation fails due to extra data being set.

```
class Timeline
{
    public function find(Request $request)
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach ($this->providers as $provider) {
            $filter = $provider->createFilter();
            $formBuilder = $this->formFactory->createNamedBuilder('', 'base_filter_type', $filter);

            $provider->configureFilter(new FilterBuilder($this->filterRegistry, $formBuilder));

            $form = $formBuilder->getForm();
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if (!$form->isSubmitted() || $form->isValid()) {
                $result = array_merge($result, $provider->find($filter));
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

In this case, there *is* a data class tied to the form. `$provider->createFilter()` simply returns an object that has properties matching the filters. The filled and validated filter object is then passed to the provider's `find()` method. E.g:

```
class EventProvider
{
    public function createFilter()
    {
        return new EventFilter();
    }

    public function find(EventFilter $filter)
    {
        // Do something with $filter and return events
    }
}

class EventFilter
{
    public $location;
    public $author;
}
```

This whole thing together makes it pretty easy to manage the filters.

To add a new type of filter:

- Implement a FormType
- Tag it in the DI as a `form.type` *and* as a `filter.type`

To start using a filter:

- Add it to the FilterBuilder in `configureFilters()`
- Add a property to the filter model
- Handle the property in the `find()` method

Answer (score 0):

Add a central `FilterHandler` where each available filter can be registered. Generic filters can be kept in the same bundle as the handler and registered from there and bundles can also register filters.

All providers should know if and when which filters they use (by the filters name). Also DI the handler in them.

From the handler you can get the complete list of registered filters and then build your filter form upon this.

When filtering call `$provider->filter($requestedFiltersWithValues)` which will check if the filters it uses are actually requested and registered (via the injected handler) and return results as needed.